# Blazor - WASM - Azure AD - Claims Customization

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

I'd like to customize claims after getting authenticating a Blazor WASM app to Azure AD.

I've found sample code like below to do this.

My problem, is that I need to call a web service from inside the ExampleClaimsPrincipalFactory to get the roles and that service requires authentication that has not yet been fully completed, therefore, calling that service from the CreateUserAsync returns a 500 error (I can call that same service successfully post login).  I've left the service call out of the sample for simplicity.

I've tried IClaimsTransformation with Azure AD, but when I try to manually get the User.Claims on a test page, it's not fired.

Setup in the Program Class

```
builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication()
.AddAccountClaimsPrincipalFactory<ExampleClaimsPrincipalFactory<RemoteUserAccount>>();
```

Factory Class

```
   public class ExampleClaimsPrincipalFactory<TAccount> : AccountClaimsPrincipalFactory<TAccount> 
    where TAccount : RemoteUserAccount
{
    public ExampleClaimsPrincipalFactory(IAccessTokenProviderAccessor accessor)
    : base(accessor)
    { 
      //Any dependency injection or construction of objects 
      //inside this constructor usually leads to wasm memory exceptions
    }

    public async override ValueTask<ClaimsPrincipal> CreateUserAsync(TAccount account, RemoteAuthenticationUserOptions options)
    {
        var user = await base.CreateUserAsync(account, options);

        if (account != null)
        {     
            //Add logic here to get custom user information
            //Add Claims to the user identity like so
            var identity = user.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("type", "value"));
        }

        return user;
    }
}
```